# Can't connect to Memcached

Tags: memcached

I know there are other questions on this but I can't find a resolution.

I've installed Memcached on a server running Ubuntu and I'm trying to use it.

I've attempted to start it using:

`$ memcached -d -p 11211`

I cannot access it using the PHP client from scripts or from Telnet `o server 11211`

Port 11211 is forwarded from the router.

What do I need to do to get it to work?

**Edit:**
I've since enabled `ufw` and added the ports to be allowed with no difference made to the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check memcached process:

```
$ ps aux | grep -E "[m]emcached"
hiemye     921  0.0  0.3  44040   868 ?        Ssl  12:31   0:00 memcached -d -p 11211
```

Check listen address:

```
$ lsof -np `pgrep memcached`
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
memcached 921 hiemye   26u  IPv4       4449      0t0    TCP *:11211 (LISTEN)
memcached 921 hiemye   27u  IPv6       4450      0t0    TCP *:11211 (LISTEN)
memcached 921 hiemye   28u  IPv4       4453      0t0    UDP *:11211 
memcached 921 hiemye   29u  IPv6       4454      0t0    UDP *:11211
```

Add allow ufw rules:

```
ufw allow in proto tcp from 192.168.0.2/32 to 192.168.0.1/32 port 11211
192.168.0.2 - client ip
192.168.0.1 - server ip
```

Comment: It doesn't appear to be on properly. Is it not working because I'm trying to access it over a network rather than from php sat on the same server?